# solr setup on htttps server?

Tags: apache, http, solr, https

I have SSL server with `https://` running website. but Now `solr` link not working with `https://` server. Can anyone please guide me here. I need to reinstall `solr` is better or need to change in already installed `solr`. which is better way. How to enable `solr` access from `https` link. Please provide some reference link how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some exra information about your setup? Where does the problem occur? Is this perhaps a client (javascript) issue? You are not allowed to call http requests from a https page.

Comment: I make call from iOS app to solr DB using `http`. but now server is `https` so it's not working. For iOS 9  we always need `https` server.

Comment: Is the certificate for the SSL server valid?

Comment: Yes. Other website working with `https://`. on same server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a look in the reference. There is a chapter named [*Managing Solr*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Managing+Solr). There is a  section named [*Enabling SSL*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Enabling+SSL).